# How to switch order of output?

Tags: java

How do I switch the order of the outcome? I would liked to be asked to enter output after the menu.

```
Welcome to the Library! Please make a selection from the menu:
1. View.
2. Show.
Enter a choice: 1
```

However, I am made to enter input first, and I see:
Enter a choice: 1
    Welcome to the Library! Please make a selection from the menu:
    1. View.
    2. Show.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Store {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Store().use();  
}


public void use() {
    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'X') {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: view(); break;
        case 2: show(); break;
        default: help(); break;
       }
    }

}
private char readChoice() {
    return In.nextChar();
} 
private String view() {
    return "";
}
private String show() {
    return "";
}

}
private void help() {
    System.out.println("Welcome! Please make a selection from the menu:");
    System.out.println("1. View.");
    System.out.println("2. Show.");    }
```

Comment: maybe case "1" ?

Comment: @Jonasw Nope, that won't compile. What about `'1'`?

Comment: @JonasW Thanks for the input. That doesn't change anything though. It is the order that I am wanting to change.

Comment: @MCEmperor  Thanks for the input. That doesn't change anything though. It is the order that I am wanting to change.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `help()` on top of the `use()` method:

```
public void use() {
    help();
    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'X') {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: view(); break;
            case 2: show(); break;
            default: help(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to change `1` and `2` into `'1'` and `'2'` respectively, because you are switching over a `char`. The fact that this compiles is because the compiler applies a *[narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)* to convert `int` to `char`.

Comment: Yeah, but who's using Java 5 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three reasons that the code does not do what you expect.

1. You are made to enter input first, because before printing anything on the console, the readChoice() function is called. Which waits until it reads one character from the console and then returns. So you must call Help() function once before the while loop.
2. I guess the switch-case will not do what you expect. I mean the view() and show() functions are not called when you enter 1 or 2. The reason is that you read 1 and 2 as characters not integers. So the switch-case should change to this:

   ```
   switch (choice) {
       case '1': view(); break; //1 changed to '1'
       case '2': show(); break; //2 changed to '2'
       default: help(); break;
   }
   ```
3. I think you might have forgotten to print "Enter a choice:" before reading the character. (I used System.out.print() rather than System.out.println() because it seems that "Enter a choice:" and the choice entered should be in the same line)

   ```
   private char readChoice() {
       System.out.print("Enter a choice:");
       return In.nextChar();
   }
   ```

this is the entire code, hope it works correctly (I put comments so you see what changes I made):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Store {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Store().use();  
}
public void use() {
    char choice;
    help();//called help() once before the loop
    while ((choice = readChoice()) != 'X') {
        switch (choice) { //cases changed
        case '1': view(); break;
        case '2': show(); break;
        default: help(); break;
       }
    }

}
private char readChoice() {
    //printing "Enter a choice:"
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    //I used Scanner class to read the next char, because I don't have 'In' class to use.
    //you might write "return In.nextChar();" insead of the following lines
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
    return c;
} 
private String view() {
    System.out.println("you selected view"); //to see this function is called
    return "";
}
private String show() {
    System.out.println("you selected show"); //to see this function is called
    return "";
}

private void help() {
    System.out.println("Welcome! Please make a selection from the menu:");
    System.out.println("1. View.");
    System.out.println("2. Show.");    
}
};
```